# Outlook / Exchange API (Microsoft Graph?)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-api

I am making a quick program that can check another users Outlook calendar and book an appointment.  The booking part is fine, but I am looking at a way to return other users calendar information, without having to link a calendar to Outlook first.

I was thinking that there would be an API or a way to access this information either via 365 or the exchange server.  There is this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Getevents) but it doesn't seem to do what I am after and is also deprecated with an end date within a year

I have read about Microsoft Graph but in reading it refers to 'users calendar', can this do calendars for a specific user that isn't me?

```
GET /me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

If so, does anyone know how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access user's calendar by calling the following endpoint

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

Resource:

[List calendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)